# what does {variable_name} in an url pattern mean in Django?

Tags: django

I'm reading Django Rest Framework documentation on router (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) and encounter this:

```
^accounts/{pk}/$
```

I understand ^ means start of line, $ means end of line and everything but {pk}. What does it mean?

Comment: That stands for "Primary Key".

Answer (score 1):

It means that an url pattern that includes a primary key, si valid. In the case of the documentation you are consulting, it means that the following url pattern is valid: `accounts/121/`. What **SimpleRouter** will do with it, is that urls that contain a primary key (`{pk}`), will be used to update or delete the **accounts** record with such primary key. In the example, account with primary key '121' would be retrieved, updated or deleted through such url.

This "variable_name" is received as a parameter by the view method or class method.

Comment: isn't that the same as <int: pk>. Why do we need a new syntax for that?